# General Question about Data Duplication / Normalization (Modelling)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller

I have the following relationships:

- Foo `has_one` Bar
- Bar `has_many` Baz
- Foo `has_many` Baz through Bar

Now my problem: I need to work with `Foo.Baz` but the information should be frozen/static.

By that I mean, whenever `Bar.Baz` changes, I don't want `Foo.Baz` to change.

In essence, `Foo.Baz` is some kind of log record that describes `Baz` at the time when `Foo` was created.

How do I best deal with this situation?

My first inclination is to just create another relationship between `Foo` and `Baz` but that would add a lot of redundant data because `Bar.Baz` will only change very occasionally.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Bas has_many Baz <-- do you mean BaR?

Comment: All this Foo is making me itch, I'd prefer an example with something graspable like Cat/Nose/Whiskers :)

Comment: You're saying "My first inclination is to just create another relationship between Foo and Baz" so does that mean the original Baz will remain untouched even when Bar.bazs changes?

Comment: What happens if you delete or modify a Baz? Extra relationship wouldn't help there. There might be something wrong with your schema design to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Could you leave it as it as and then create some scopes to get Foo.Baz based on the timestamps and not allow updates to Bar.Baz, just creates. So to get Foo.Baz, you'd get the latest

`Bar.Baz when Bar.Foo == foo and Bar.baz.created_at < Foo.created_at.`

I realize this isn't a great solution, but it may be a starting point...